# Delay Stopping AWS EC2 Instance from Lambda until User is Inactive

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, boto3

I am using a simple AWS Lambda function to stop EC2 instances given a region and instance IDs (see python code below). The Lambda function is being triggered by an AWS CloudWatch rule (specifically a schedule everyday at 6pm). This has all been tested and works.

```
import boto3
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    region = event.get('region')
    instances = event.get('instances')
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    print 'started your instance: ' + str(instances)
```

If a user is actively logged into the EC2 instance and the function is triggered, the EC2 instance will force shutdown the instance.

So, is there a way (either in CloudWatch or Lambda) to delay and/or ignore the shutdown until either the user is inactive or totally logged out? Perhaps using boto3 code?

**UPDATE:**

Considered using a waiter, but the only one I could find waits until the instance is in use, as opposed to not in use. Perhaps there is a wait for that? Also considered CloudWatch alarms, which works for stopping an instance after a period of inactivity, but not for triggering at an exact time.

```
waiter = ec2.get_waiter('volume_in_use')
waiter.wait(
    WaiterConfig={
    'Delay': 900, # In Seconds (900 = 15 mins)
    'MaxAttempts': 47 # Number of Attempts (47 = 11.75 hours)
    }
) # Default wait is 15 seconds 40 times
```

Comment: The instance will be shut down regardless a user is logged in or not. There is no out of box functionality to check and postpone the shutdown (until you don't implement it yourself)

Comment: @gusto2 I was afraid that was the case.. I wonder if there is a check I can make in the python code to see if anyone is active?

Comment: you can stil invoke the `w` or `who` utility on the ec2 instance (not directly fom lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Lambda can utilize SSM Run command to check if anyone is logged in locally before initiating the shutdown.

Comment: Do you have an example of the run command? And how to put it in the lambda function as a check?

Comment: This is a good example that shows how to send the command, collect the ids, wait for a result and get the output.  https://github.com/drkmrin78/pineapple-networks/blob/master/lambda-functions.py